# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WebTestCase in C:\wamp\www\testapp\protected\tests\WebTest ase.php on line 17

Tags: selenium, yii, phpunit, testcase

i am using phpunit with selenium in yii to test default created testing cases.

when i am trying to run SiteTest.php file from tests folder then its giving error like
    Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WebTestCase in C:\wamp\www\testapp\protected\tests\WebTest ase.php on line 17
and when i am trying to run from functional folder then its showing CWebTestCase not defined

i am running this command from command line 
  protected\test>phpunit functional/SiteTest.php

system configuration 
window 7 64 bit
phpunit is installed
selenium is installed
pear is installed
latest version of all with latest version of yii as well. please help me asap.

regards
anil

Comment: what errors do you get in selenium server?

Comment: Can you post the code in `C:\wamp\www\testapp\protected\tests\WebTest ase.php`?